# Python Progress Bar Is Showing An Extra %

Tags: python, progress-bar

So I was following a YouTube tutorial for a progress bar in python and when its done, an extra "%" appears.
(NOTE: I changed a few variables in the code in order to have the needed product.)
Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1eaT88vJUA&ab_channel=NeuralNine

`

```
import math
import colorama

def progress_bar(progress, total, color=colorama.Fore.YELLOW):
    percent=100 * (progress / float(total))
    bar='■' * int(percent) + '-' * (100 - int(percent))
    print(color + f"\r|{bar}| {percent: .0f}%", end="\r")
    if progress==total:
        print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + f"\r|{bar}| {percent:.0f}%", end="\r")
numbers=[x * 5 for x in range(1000)]
results=[]
progress_bar(0, len(numbers))
for i, x in enumerate(numbers):
    results.append(math.factorial(x))
    progress_bar(i + 1, len(numbers))
print(colorama.Fore.RESET)
```

`

I tried to fix it on many different ways and the only one I found is to fully remove the "%" from the code.

Comment: What is `len(colorama.Fore.YELLOW)` vs. `len(colorama.Fore.GREEN)`? Try removing them both.

Comment: It's a python color formating, that is not a problem, i found it and it's a missing space.

Comment: Wow, that was subtle. I looked at that code 10 times and didn't see it.

Comment: Ye I didn't see it either. Its in line 8 after the "%" because the print is overwriting and it's shorter, just look at the thing I marked as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite simple.

The program draws a bar on the same terminal line overwriting the previous text. Last 3 lines look like this:

```
yellow bar|  99%
yellow bar|  100%
 green bar| 100%_
                ^
```

As you see the last yellow line is longer that the final green line and the last character remains not overwritten.

One way to fix is not to draw the 100% line first in yellow and then in green.

Update: as noted by the OP, the length difference was due to a missing space and he fixed it that way.

Comment: Tysm, I've been looking for the problem for a long time and it's just a missing space.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) library instead of reinventing the wheel :). It's very customizable.

Here is a demo:

[image]

Comment: I know this one is easier but I don't like all of these numbers on the right when its loading. I'm still trying to fnd a way to fix my code and you are free to help.

Comment: As i said, it is customizable and you can remove those numbers. The demo just shows a lot of what is possible with the library. See the documentation on the link I provided on how to make it fit your use case.

Comment: Tysm but I found the problem. I may use it in the future.